# Toggle() function elements not disappearing properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have been building a `toggle` function to display a sub menu (`.li-one`) when the main menu (`.ul-one`) is clicked and then have the sub menu disappear when another part of the page is selected. Works fine when clicking any other part of the page `HOWEVER`, when you click another menu function (`.ul-one`), the previous will not disappear - it only disappears when you click something unrelated (outside of the `.main-nav` div). Can anyone modify so the sub-menu ALWAYS disappears regardless - for example: if you click `element 1` and then `element 2` - `element 1` sub-menu will disappear? Code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".li-one").hide();
    $('.ul-one') .click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".li-one",this).slideToggle("medium"); 
    });
    $(".ul-one").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.ul-one {
    border:1px black solid;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.li-one {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="ul-one">
        <a>Element 1</a>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.1</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.2</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.3</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul-one">
        <a>Element 2</a>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.1</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.2</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.3</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul-one">
        <a>Element 3</a>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.1</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.2</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.3</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul-one">
        <a>Element 4</a>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.1</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.2</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.3</a></li>
        <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make runnable snippet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the click target and check if the desire element exist.

```
$lis = $(".ul-one .li-one").hide();

$("ul.ul-one").on("click", function(event) {
    $lis.not($(this).find('li')).slideUp("medium");
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle("medium");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".main-nav").on("click", function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(".ul-one")) {
        $lis.slideUp("medium");
    }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $lis = $(".ul-one .li-one").hide();

  $("ul.ul-one").on("click", function(event) {
    $lis.not($(this).find('li')).slideUp("medium");
    $(this).find('li').slideToggle("medium");
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(".main-nav").on("click", function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(".ul-one")) {
      $lis.slideUp("medium");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.ul-one {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.li-one {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <a>Element 1</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <a>Element 2</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <a>Element 3</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <a>Element 4</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Prs, this was the closest solution - the only problem is that it disabled when I clicked outside the ul. To fix this I added the following to the bottom and it worked exactly how I wanted it to.                       $(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".li-one").hide("slow");
});

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".li-one").hide();

  $('.ul-one').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".li-one").hide();//hide all
    $(".li-one", this).slideToggle("medium");
  });
  $(".ul-one").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.ul-one {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.li-one {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">

  <ul class="ul-one"><a>Element 1</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 1.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-one"><a>Element 2</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 2.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-one"><a>Element 3</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 3.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-one"><a>Element 4</a>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-one"><a>List Element 4.4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

1. Hide all sub menu on button click then show the respective submenu

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $(".li-one").hide();

 $('.ul-one').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   $('.ul-one').not(this).find('.li-one').slideUp("medium");//slideUp all but the current selected ones

   $(".li-one", this).slideToggle("medium");
 });
 $(".ul-one").on("click", function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x57g649h/

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$('.ul-one') .click(function(event){
```

to

```
$('.ul-one').click(function(event){
```